# Sorrting employees by employee id(XXX-L) where X is a number and L is a letter

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, inheritance

So I have my program completed and prints out what I was asked minus being sorted by employee id. I cannot for the life of me figure out what to do. This is for a second level intro class and we have just gone over inheritance. Here is my program in full:

EMPLOYEE CLASS

```
public abstract class Employee {

    private String eName, eNum, hireDate;

    public Employee(String eName, String eNum, String hireDate){
        this.eName = eName;
        this.eNum = eNum;
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }
    public void setEName(String eName){
        this.eName = eName;
    }
    public String getEName(){
        return eName;
    }

    public void setENum(String eNum){
        this.eNum = eNum;
    }
    public String getENum(){
        return eNum;
    }

    public void setHireDate(String hireDate){
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }
    public String getHireDate(){
        return hireDate;
    }
}
```

PRODUCTION WORKER CLASS

```
public class ProductionWorker extends Employee{

private int shift, hoursWorked;
private double payRate;

public ProductionWorker(String eName, String eNum, String hireDate, int shift,
        int hoursWorked, double payRate) {
    super(eName, eNum, hireDate);
    this.setShift(shift);
    this.setPayRate(payRate);
    this.setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
}

public int getShift() {
    return shift;
}
public void setShift(int shift) {
    this.shift = shift;
}

public int getHoursWorked() {
    return hoursWorked;
}
public void setHoursWorked(int hoursWorked) {
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public double getPayRate() {
    return payRate;
}
public void setPayRate(double payRate) {
    this.payRate = payRate;
}

public String toString(){
    if (shift == 1){
        double pay = payRate * (int)hoursWorked;
        return "Employee name: " + getEName() + "\nEmployee number: " + getENum()
                + "\nHire date: " + getHireDate() + "\nShift: " + getShift() + 
                "\nHourly pay Rate: " + getPayRate() + "\nHours worked: " + getHoursWorked()
                + "\nPay for the week: " + pay + "\n";
    }
    else if (shift == 2){
        double pay = payRate * 1.25 * (int)hoursWorked;
        return "Employee name: " + getEName() + "\nEmployee number: " + getENum()
        + "\nHire date: " + getHireDate() + "\nShift: " + getShift() + 
        "\nHourly pay Rate: " + getPayRate() + "\nHours worked: " + getHoursWorked()
        + "\nPay for the week: " + pay + "\n";
    }
    else return "Invalid shift number.";
}
```

}

WEEKLY WORKER CLASS

```
public class WeeklyWorker extends Employee{

private double salary, otPerDiem;
private int hoursWorked;

public WeeklyWorker(String eName, String eNum, String hireDate,
        double salary, double otPerDiem, int hoursWorked) {
    super(eName, eNum, hireDate);
    this.salary = salary;
    this.otPerDiem = otPerDiem;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public double getOtPerDiem() {
    return otPerDiem;
}
public void setOtPerdiem(double otPerDiem) {
    this.otPerDiem = otPerDiem;
}

public int getHoursWorked() {
    return hoursWorked;
}
public void setHoursWorked(int hoursWorked) {
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public String toString(){
    if (hoursWorked == 40){
        return "Employee name: " + getEName() + "\nEmployee number: " + getENum()
        + "\nHire date: " + getHireDate() + "\nWeekly salary: " + getSalary() + 
        "\nOvertime per diem: " + getOtPerDiem() + "\nHours worked: " + getHoursWorked()
        + "\nPay for the week: " + getSalary() + "\n";
    }
    else if(hoursWorked > 40){
        double pay = salary + (((hoursWorked - 40)/8)*otPerDiem);
        return "Employee name: " + getEName() + "\nEmployee number: " + getENum()
        + "\nHire date: " + getHireDate() + "\nWeekly salary: " + getSalary() + 
        "\nOvertime per diem: " + getOtPerDiem() + "\nHours worked: " + getHoursWorked()
        + "\nPay for the week: " + pay + "\n";
    }
    else return "Invalid entry.";
}
```

}

TESTER CLASS

```
public class TestEmployee {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee [] eList = new Employee[6];
    eList[0] = new ProductionWorker("Bill", "234-H", "10/31/2010", 1, 10, 40);
    eList[1] = new ProductionWorker("Joe", "651-J", "11/23/2011", 2, 13, 26);
    eList[2] = new WeeklyWorker("Jerry", "982-K", "01/03/2013", 1200, 30, 52);
    eList[3] = new ProductionWorker("Sandy", "492-B", "05/20/2009", 2, 16, 32);
    eList[4] = new ProductionWorker("Sherry", "123-A", "08/05/2000", 1, 20, 38);
    eList[5] = new WeeklyWorker("Halley", "623-M", "07/03/1995", 1650, 50, 60);

    for (int i = 0; i < eList.length; i++){
        System.out.println(eList[i]+"\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see any sorting in your code. Your tester class is just printing out the array in order.

Comment: ... unless I mis-read this and you're asking us to write the sorting code for you, in which case, better to try something yourself first and we can help debug. If this is for an intro class, I'm sure your instructor has given you some hint of where to start..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html